# OxyPlot export to PNG

Tags: wpf, charts, save, oxyplot

Im trying to export chart to PNG. That is my code:

Chart.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="P1.Chart"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:P1"
    Title="Example 1 (WPF)" Height="800" Width="800"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

<Grid>
    <oxy:Plot>
        <oxy:Plot.Axes>
            <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" Minimum="-20" Maximum="20" />
            <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" Minimum="-20" Maximum="20" />
        </oxy:Plot.Axes>

        <oxy:Plot.Series>
            <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Points1}" LineStyle="None"  MarkerType="Circle" MarkerSize="3" MarkerFill="Red" Title="Point 1"/>
            <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Points2}" LineStyle="None"  MarkerType="Circle" MarkerSize="3" MarkerFill="Green" Title="Point 2"/>
            <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Points3}" LineStyle="None"  MarkerType="Circle" MarkerSize="3" MarkerFill="Blue" Title="Point 3"/>   
        </oxy:Plot.Series>
    </oxy:Plot>
</Grid>
```

Chart.xaml.cs

```
    namespace P1
{
    public partial class Chart: Window
    {
        public IList<DataPoint> Points1 { get;  set; }
        public IList<DataPoint> Points2 { get; set; }
        public IList<DataPoint> Points3 { get; set; }

    public Chart(Learn x1)
    {      

        this.Points1 = new List<DataPoint>
        {
            new DataPoint(Convert.ToDouble(a1),a2),
        };

        this.Points2 = new List<DataPoint>
        {
            new DataPoint(b1,b2),
        };

        this.Points3 = new List<DataPoint>
        {
            new DataPoint(c1,c2),
        };

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Is it possible to save Chart window in PNG by using code below?

```
    var pngExporter = new PngExporter { Width = 600, Height = 400, Background = OxyColors.White };
    pngExporter.ExportToFile(plotModel, fileName);
```

I dont have plotmodel cause i bind all in xaml, do u have any advice?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to export from code behind, you can go with:

```
<oxy:Plot x:Name="Plot">
```

```cs
PngExporter.Export(this.Plot.ActualModel, fileName, 600, 400, OxyColors.White)
```